# File name in function

Tags: php, logging, ip

I have file called functions.php, where I have function to log IP address of visitor. Function is used in multiple pages, so I want to have name of page in the log. Code looks like this:

```
function ipLog($path) {
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $data = $content . "\n" . basename(__FILE__, '.php') . ';' . $ip . ';' . date('Y.n.d H:i');
    file_put_contents($path, $data);
}
```

Problem is that it always return functions.php and not name of page which it is included in. Any ideas?

---

EDIT: I used

```
$file = debug_backtrace();
$file = $file[0];
$data = $content . "\n" . basename($file['file']) . ';' . $ip . ';' . date('Y.n.d.H.i');
```

Thanks very much.

---

EDIT: final version:

```
function ipLog($path = './log/ipLog.txt') {
    file_put_contents($path, date('Y.n.d.H.i.s') . ';' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ';' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ';' . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Yes it returns the file name of the file where it is called. It's the intended behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use

```
debug_backtrace();
```

Which will tell you where the function was called from, and then use that value eg:

```
$called_from = debug_backtrace();

$data = $content . "\n" . $called_from[0] . ';' . $ip . ';' . date('Y.n.d H:i');
```

read more about this function [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: nice one, could you accept the answer if it was correct please